# How to solve NoSuchElement in java?

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

It works well on Intellij.
However, NoSuchElement appears on the algorithmic solution site.
I know that NoSuchElement is a problem caused by trying to receive it even though there is no value entered.
But I wrote it so that the problem of NoSuchElement doesn't occur.
Because given str, the for statement executes. Given "END", the if statement is executed. And because it ends with "break;".
I don't know what the problem is.

Algorithm problem: Arrange the reverse sentence correctly.
My code for algorithmic problems

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = scan.nextLine();
            if(str.equals("END")){
                break;
            }
            for (int i = str.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

> !edoc doog a tahW
> erafraw enirambus detcirtsernu yraurbeF fo tsrif eht no nigeb ot dnetni eW
> END

**Expected**

> What a good code!
> We intend to begin on the first of February unrestricted submarine warfare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when there is no input at all, for example when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> or run your code like `echo "" | java Main.java`.

To avoid this, check that the `Scanner` actually has input before trying to grab the next line. Pull `scan` out of the loop, there is no point to create a new `Scanner` for each line anyway. Then use `hasNext` to see if there is input.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String str = scan.nextLine();
            if(str.equals("END")){
                break;
            }
            for (int i = str.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```